# C: Incompatible pointer type initializing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to learn C. I'm currently on pointers so I've decided to write some code to see how it works. However the code works as intended (i.e. it adds chars a-j in an array and prints it on the console) but I'm get warnings about incompatible pointer assignment. I've added the warnings as comments on the lines were the warnings are given.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    #define MAX 10

    char* c[MAX]; // pointer to the 1st element in the array
    char* pointer = &c; // Warning: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'char *(*)[10]'
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        *pointer = 'a' + j;
        pointer++;
    }

    pointer = &c; // Warning: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'char *' from 'char *(*)[10]'
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        printf("i[%d] = %c\n", j, *pointer);
        ++pointer;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why I'm getting these warnings?

```
char* pointer = &c; & pointer = &c;
```

I understand the code I'm writing as follows declare a char pointer called pointer and assign the address of the 1st element in the array to the pointer.

PS! please don't comment on how to achieve the same result with better written code as I'm trying to learn here about pointers and arrays. So while this may be a verbose way to achieve this result, I feel it is syntactically correct, so if I've got this wrong please help me understand.

Comment: At this stage in your C career, if the compiler disagrees with you about something being valid, assume the compiler is correct.  It knows a lot more about C than you do and the chances of you uncovering a bug in the compiler are infinitesimal.  (Note that C is a case-sensitive language; get used to typing questions and code with capitals in appropriate places.  And the language is C, not 'c'.)

Comment: @Jonathan completely agree and this is why i'm asking the question. The code actually does what i want it to do but if the complier is complaining i'm must have not understood something. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
char* pointer = &c
```

to

```
char* pointer = c[0];
```

`c` elements type is `char *` but `&c` type is a pointer to `c` type.

**EDIT**: This will fix your warning but the problem is you are dealing with the wrong types first.

Instead of:

```
char* c[MAX];
char* pointer = &c;
```

use:

```
char c[MAX];
char *pointer = c;
```

In your program you are storing characters, so you need an array of `char` and not an array of `char *` elements.

Same for `pointer = &c;` which then has to be `pointer = c;`.

Comment: Yes, but why? isn't this just the same thing? i.e. char* pointer = &c[0]; this line just says pointer points to the 1st element in the array. Same as char* pointer = &c; So why am i getting the warning?

Comment: @Sheedy75 Because the type of `&c` is not `char*`. See my answer.

Comment: @Sheedy75 `char* c[MAX]; char* pointer = &c[0];` because here `c[0]` is of type `char *` (it is the element of an array of `char *`!), so `&c[0]` will take a pointer to this element, which means a `char **`.

Comment: FYI- add this line in Xcode main.c file and i get the following warning:  Incompatible pointer types initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'char **'; remove &

Comment: This is how i wrote the code when i first read the chapter but what confused me is i read that char* c[MAX]; just declares a pointer to the 1st element in the array. So from my basic understand this is just holding the memory address of c[0];

Comment: @Sheedy75 Maybe you read an April fool's day hoax. But "char* c[MAX]; just declares a pointer to the 1st element in the array" it totally wrong.

Comment: Sorry my bad!. However my code works and does what i want it to do but is syntactically incorrect. when i make this assignment char* pointer = &c; i'm actually storing the address of what c[0] is pointing too i.e. the address of the 1st element of my char array. However the complier see this as the address of the pointer pointing to the 1st array and raises a warning.

Comment: BTW i added two print f statements like so: 'code' printf("address of pointer: %p\n", pointer);  printf("address of c: %p\n", c); 'code' and i got the following result: address of pointer: 0x7fff5fbff780 and address of c: 0x7fff5fbff780

Answer (score 3):

`c` is an array of pointers to `char`:

```
char* c[MAX];
```

The type of this expression

```
&c
```

is "pointer to a length-`MAX` array of pointers to `char`", or

```
char *(*)[MAX]
```

The compiler is warning you that you're initializing a pointer of one type from one of another type.

It isn't clear what you intended to do with your code, but a valid initialization of a `char*` with no conversions would be

```
char* pointer = c[0];
```

A valid initialization from `&c` (pointer to an array of pointers), would be

```
char *(*pointer)[MAX] = &c;
```

Alternatively, you can let the array "decay" to a pointer to its first element by omitting the address-of operator `&`", but this yields a pointer to pointer:

```
char** pointer = c;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code it seems that you declared the array the wrong way, it should be

```
char c[MAX];
```

which is an array of `char`, not an array of `char` pointers, then

```
char *pointer;
pointer = c;
```

where `pointer` **is** a *pointer to the first element of `c`*, and the rest of the code will work as you expected.

Also, I am a bit curious why did you define the `MAX` macro inside `main()`, just in case you didn't know, it's not being declared it's substituted by the prepropcessor before compilation, so where you put it in the code is completely irrelevant.

Comment: i decided to use Xcode today as it gave me intelli-sense (i was using gedit before) and Xcode complains and doesn't let me compile the code. e.g. "Use of undeclared identifier 'MAX'" - if i declare it outside the main function. However i understand the preprocessor part. Maybe i'm going to go back to gedit and Makefiles

Comment: Or try to see if `Xcode` can be configured to understand preprocessor macros, qtcretor has a smart parser that can know even if the preprocessor macros was enabled or disabled by the Makefile.

Comment: Yes got this sorted as well. In Xcode you can go to the Build settings and set "Precompiled Header Uses Files From Build Directory" to No.